# Turn off unneeded Google Drive permission

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api, google-drive-realtime-api

In my app, I have requested users' permissions for their google sheets. However, there are 2 showing up. I don't think I need 1. because 2. is good enough. How can I **turn it off** or change to **access only the spreadsheets opened or created with this app**?

```
1. View and manage your spreadsheets in Google Drive

2. View and manage Google Drive files and folders that you have opened or created with this app
```

Comment: What api services are you utilizing?

Comment: @DouglasGaskell I'm using Google spreadsheet APIs and Google Drive APIs, but I don't need to access user's spreadsheets. I only need to access the spreadsheets my app created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your comment, you are utilizing these two Services:

- Spreadsheet Service

  - Requires authorization to access and manage sheets in drive. Even a single spreadsheet, regardless of the owner, requires this authorization.
- Drive Service

  - Requires authorization to access and manage drive files. But this does not grant permissions to modify these files through other services such as the Spreadsheet Service .

Each of these require a different authorization set. Which is why you see two different requested permissions. This does not mean that the app now has access to every sheet on that users drive, it still only has access to the sheets that are appropriately shared with the user the script is executing as. [See this answer as well, which is marginally related.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21764642/google-apps-script-user-must-give-permission-on-own-drive-to-open-spreadsheet-in)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove app-permission 1 from showing, you may manage users and limit app-specific permissions by using the "Role" drop-down to select a predefined role for a user or check individual boxes to turn on permission that apply to all apps in your account. Here's how:

> 1. Sign in to your Google Play Developer Console.
> 2. Click Settings.
> 3. On the left menu, click **User accounts & rights**.
> 4. Near the right side of a row, click the Settings Gear icon.
> 5. Select **Add app specific rights**.
> 6. Click the search box to find or select an app.
>
>    - You can select multiple apps to add permissions for multiple apps at once.
> 7. Check boxes to add permissions.
> 8. Click **Add rights**.
>
>    - To remove app-specific rights, click the **X** next to a permission on the User accounts & rights page.

Developer Console Help - [Add developer account users & manage permissions](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/2528691?hl=en) might help.